# Point of quoting multiple times in lisp? (eg '''''a)

Tags: lisp, evaluation, quote

Is there a use in being able to `quote` multiple times?

Like `'a` is different from `''a` and `(quote a)` is different from `(quote (quote a))`

I mean, why not have it so that `''a` is the same as `'a` or even `''''''''a`. `quote` would quote if the argument it's given has not been quoted already and that way  `''''a` would evaluate to `'a`.

The way it is feels wrong to me because I think the question should be: is it quoted? and not how many times has it been quoted? none? once? a 100 times?

Comment: there's no point, but there's no problem as well...

Comment: I do not consider this "not constructive" or "too localized". What's with the dumb voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is. When the expression is evaluated more than once and you need to pass the expression through more than one evaluation as is. Remember, when writing macros, the expression is usually evaluated twice (once during expansion and once as the macro result) and in some rare cases may need to be evaluated even more times.

Comment: In macros, you're more likely to see multiple-evaluation-round protection give rise to patterns like `,',','` rather than consecutive quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Nesting quotes is largely useless. It might happen in the output of a compiler for the backquote syntax, but I can't think of any reason why you would do that, even in nested macros. If you find yourself cascading quotes, that probably means you've inserted the expression in a backquote template at the wrong unquote level.

Concretely, suppose you have written something like this:

`````
````(,,,,'''''a)  ;; goal is to be left with ('a) at the end of four eval rounds
`````

But here, the commas and quotes basically cancel and you can do it like this:

`````
````('a)
`````

There is no need to assign the form `''''a` to the innermost backquote, and have it work backwards toward `'a` across multiple evaluations. Just assign `'a` to the outermost level and you're done.

Another example would be a slight modification of the above. We expect four evaluation rounds to happen, and in the very last round `a` is substituted for the binding which it has in the environment of that evaluation:

`````
````(,,,,''''a)  ;; only four quotes this time
`````

So now, after three `eval`s of the result of the above backquote, we are left with `(a)` and if we `eval` that, it wants to call the function `a`. But, again, we could achieve the same thing like this:

`````
````(a)
`````

Exactly like before, three `evals` produce `(a)` and one more wants to call `a`.

Now what if the symbol `a` is not literally `a`, but computed? Say `a` is to be replaced by `b`:

`````
 (let ((a 'b))
   ````(,,,''',a))
`````

The substitution has to happen in the first evaluation of the backquote, inside the `let`, and so the `b` needs four commas on the left, so that it connects to the outermost backquote. The resulting object is equivalent to

````
 ```(,,,'''a)
````

In this example, we cannot just cancel the three commas and quotes. However, the customary way is to have the two interspersed:

`````
 (let ((a 'b))
   ````(,',',',a)) ;; instead of ,,,''',a
`````

Each evaluation round strips away a quote but then adds one back.  The first substitution replaces `,a` with `b`, but then protects it with the quote. Then in the next round, the comma before that quote causes `,'b` to be replaced with `b`, but another quote before that protects it once again, and so on.

That is to say, the two situations in which you might see directly compounded quotes doing something useful would be: triply (or more) nested backquote (rare to begin with!) in which someone used `,,'',expr` instead of `,',',expr`; and superfluous use of multiple quotes used to combat the multiple evaluation of some form that was needlessly submerged into multiple evaluation rounds.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaz is no doubt right about usual practice, but I would agree with @JanHudec about what is appropriate for CL.  `'a` means the same thing as `(quote a)`, and `''a` means the same thing as `(quote (quote a))`.  What you're suggesting, user1076329, is that evaluating `(quote (quote a))` should have the same result as evaluating `(quote a)`.  It feels contrary to the spirit of CL to make it difficult for a function to return `'a`.  (Suppose, for example, that you were writing a program that would generate Lisp source code to be written to a file and evaluated later?  Or writing a program that generates Lisp source code for a program that writes Lisp programs?  Lisp is designed to make it easy to do this sort of thing.)  You can and should use macros in many cases, but in essence a macro is just way of constructing lists and then evaluating them.  You should be able to construct the same lists without macros or backquote, even if they make it easier.